# git rebase -i --root creates unrelated history

Tags: git, rebase

Say I have the following commit history:

```
* E   (HEAD -> mybranch, origin/mybranch) Foo 3
|
* D   Foo 2
|
* C   Update readme
|
* B   Foo 1
|
* A   Initial commit
```

I want to rebase from the initial commit and drop all commits named "Foo", so I run

```
git rebase -i --root
```

However, this creates a new, unrelated history like this:

```
* C'  (HEAD -> mybranch) Update readme
|
* A'  Initial commit

* E   (origin/mybranch) Foo 3
|
* D   Foo 2
|
* C   Update readme
|
* B   Foo 1
|
* A   Initial commit
```

On the other hand, if I run

```
git rebase -i A  # where "A" is the commit SHA
```

I get the expected branching behaviour:

```
* C'  (HEAD -> mybranch) Update readme
|
| * E   (origin/mybranch) Foo 3
| |
| * D   Foo 2
| |
| * C   Update readme
| |
| * B   Foo 1
|/
* A   Initial commit
```

So why does `git rebase --root` behave to produce an unrelated history and can I make it behave like I expected?

Comment: You need to include the steps you took in the interactive rebase when you did the `git rebase -i --root` option.

Comment: Specifying `--root` makes the rebase operate on every commit, the net result is that you will essentially create a new root as well. You said "from the initial commit", do you mean that you want to leave the initial commit alone? If so then using `--root` is not what you want, but instead the second command is what you want.

Comment: My question to you is why you want `--root` to behave like the second command if the second command does what you want. Can't you simply use the second command then?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen literally just `drop` all commits named `Foo` and leave the others as `pick`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I want to rebase starting with the initial commit without finding out its SHA

Comment: `--root` is *guaranteed* to make unrelated history. That's the point of `--root`. (To find the hash ID of the root of the current commit, use `git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD`.  You can make a name for this commit if you like, or just do it as many times as needed.)

Answer (score 0):

After setting up a GitHub Actions workflow that to do `git rebase --root` like in the question, it turns out it *doesn't* create an unrelated history, unlike when I run the command on my git version `2.24.1.windows.2`. So it might be that they patched the behaviour in a more recent version of git.